# save to localstorage using setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a quiz with stopwatch, to calculate how much time user spent answering the quiz. But it's hackable by the user if the user refresh the browser.

Hmm what should I do? should I save the the counter to localstorage every seconds? and resume?

Comment: Write a webservice & save it there!!

Comment: Storage is also hackable - It's terribly easy: F12, Resources, LocalStorage > "Edit Value". You should save it to the server.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: :-) Or even: F12, Console, `localStorage.setItem("quizstart", timeInFuture);`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, but a "hacker" will first go sniff the easiest way ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Indeed. :-)

Comment: Do it on server side

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan what if my quiz is used for on-site quiz, I don't think they can inspect storage in mobile. at least not for a normal user.

Answer (score 3):

No, local storage is entirely under the control of the user as well.

You'll need to track the information server-side: Have the server record when user X started task Y, and have the server record when they completed it. Nothing you can do client-side will be resistant to an even modest attempt at bypassing.

Even the server approach can be susceptible to bypassing by bad actors (for instance, I sign up for multiple accounts, get all my answers together, and then sign up "for real" and take the quiz in record time). You'll always be in an arms race (IP checking, etc.), but at least you'll have *some* small chance by using something somewhat outside the user's control.

Comment: so pump data every seconds to the db?!

Comment: @EuniceChia: No, just when events occur that you need (somewhat) reliable timing information for.

Comment: so insert time to db when user refresh? it doesn't matter sense.

Comment: @EuniceChia: No, notify the server when you need to record some information. In order for this to work, you'll need the users to register, because you can't reliably track them otherwise. So again, when user X starts the quiz, record that they started it on the server. Then it doesn't matter how many times they refresh, the server knows when they really started.